# when more dialogs opened causes memory error

Tags: android, memory, android-dialogfragment

I'm listing items in RecyclerView. If you click each item, detailed information pop-ups via DialogFragment/AppCompatDialogFragment. After about 30 impressions I get a memory error and application crashes.

I close dialogs with `dismiss()`. Also I used `android:largeHeap="true"` It only increases impression number. Finally, app crashes again.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

What can I do? What are your suggestions?

fragment_item.class

```
public class FragmentSingle extends DialogFragment {

    private Item item;

    public FragmentSingle() {
    }

    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullScreenDialog);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        FragmentItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.fragment_item, null, false
        );

        binding.setItem(item);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

fragment_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="...Item" />

    </data>


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            loadImage="@{item.image}"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</layout>
```

```
    @BindingAdapter("loadImage")
    public static void loadImage(View view, String url) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
        Picasso.get()
                .load(url)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(imageView);

    }
```

Comment: android:largeHeap=true should be only used when your application ACTUALLY needs it. It sounds like garbage collection event is not happening. Are you using any statics variables or using global context to perform dialog actions? We can`t tell unless we see the code.

Comment: You clearly have a memory leak. Are you sure you release all the resources that you use in the dialog and in the activity/fragment that shows the dialog? If in the onResume of the activity, for example, you allocate some resources that you don't release  then you get the OOM. If you are showing images in the RecyclerView, be sure that you are releasing the memory when you can.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I added code @TaseerAhmad

Comment: I think I am not relasing resources @kingston

Comment: I believe that way you have overridden your onCreateView and inflating from "getContext()" may be the issue. Since getContext returns the context of the 'activity' that the fragment is associated with, which in your case is a dialog fragment. So each fragment initialized is bound to the activity. BTW, I don`t have experience with data binding, it would be great if you edit the tags and add data binding to it.

Comment: Thank you @TaseerAhmad I think Picasso caching causes the problem. Now, I'm using Fresco. Problem solved :)